# Create element and then drag it increasing the width

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'me trying to create an element inside another container and then drag it increasing the width of the same.

I can create it just can't drag it check the codepen please. Thank you

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init(){
        var i, positionId = [];
        for(i = 1; i< 7 ; i++){
          positionId[i - 1]= document.getElementById(i.toString());
          positionId[i-1].addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
        }
      }

function getPosition(e){
        var x;
        console.log(e);
        x = e.offsetX;
  $(document.createElement('div'))
      .addClass('time-sch-div').appendTo(e.toElement).css('left', x);
        $( 'time-sch-div' ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYmxZx

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use jquery animate? It is very easy and convenient.
[Jquery Animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)